# K8S Namespace tolerations whitelist conflict

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

1. I have been trying to make use of Azure Spot instances on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) - version 1.19.11 and to enable scheduling of pods onto those nodes, I am trying to use the `PodTolerationRestriction` admission controller.
2. I can confirm that the PodTolerationRestriction controller is enabled as I am having no issues deploying a replicaset to the default namespace. This is another namespace but we are not specifically adding any tolerations while creating it.
3. I gathered from elsewhere that, along with whitelisting against a specific taint (in my case spot), it is also necessary to whitelist certain default tolerations. As a result, I have added certain annotations to my namespace.
4. I do not have any additional tolerations pre-defined for this statefulset.
5. The node has taints - the first two are taken care of through the helm chart values

   - RabbitMQ=true:NoSchedule
   - Allow=true:NoExecute
   - kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority=spot:NoSchedule

I am wondering what additional tolerations need to be whitelisted.

The annotations I added -

```
scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/defaultTolerations: '[{"operator": "Equal", "value": "spot", "key": "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority"}]'
scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerationsWhitelist: '[{"operator": "Equal", "value": "spot", "key": "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority"}, {"operator": "Exists", "effect": "NoSchedule", "key": "node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure"}, {"operator": "Exists", "tolerationSeconds": 300, "effect": "NoExecute", "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable"}, {"operator": "Exists", "tolerationSeconds": 300, "effect": "NoExecute", "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready"}]'
```

Statefulset describe -

```
Name:               <release name>
Namespace:          <namespace>
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 18 Jan 2022 19:37:38 +0530
Selector:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=<name>,app.kubernetes.io/name=rabbitmq
Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/instance=rabbit
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=rabbitmq
                    helm.sh/chart=rabbitmq-8.6.1
Annotations:        meta.helm.sh/release-name: <release name>
                    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: <namespace>
Replicas:           3 desired | 0 total
Update Strategy:    RollingUpdate
Pods Status:        0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=rabbit
                    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=rabbitmq
                    helm.sh/chart=rabbitmq-8.6.1
  Annotations:      checksum/config: 1a138ded5a3ade049cbee9f4f8e2d0fd7253c126d49b790495a492601fd9f280
                    checksum/secret: 05af38634eb4b46c2f8db5770013e1368e78b0d5af057aed5fa4fe7eec4c92de
                    prometheus.io/port: 9419
                    prometheus.io/scrape: true
  Service Account:  sa-rabbitmq
  Containers:
   rabbitmq:
    Image:       docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.9-debian-10-r64
    Ports:       5672/TCP, 25672/TCP, 15672/TCP, 4369/TCP, 9419/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Liveness:    exec [/bin/bash -ec rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping] delay=120s timeout=200s period=30s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:   exec [/bin/bash -ec rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_running && rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_local_alarms] delay=10s timeout=200s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      <multiple environment variables>
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/rabbitmq/conf from configuration (rw)
      /bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia from data (rw)
  Volumes:
   configuration:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      rabbit-rabbitmq-config
    Optional:  false
   data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
Volume Claims:  <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                 From                    Message
  ----     ------        ----                ----                    -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  31s (x14 over 72s)  statefulset-controller  create Pod <pod-name> in StatefulSet <release name> failed error: pod tolerations (possibly merged with namespace default tolerations) conflict with its namespace whitelist
```

Comment: Can you add more information - Kubernetes version, is PodTolerationRestriction admission controller enabled? https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#which-plugins-are-enabled-by-default Also, can you add yaml description of you StatefulSet resource?  Have your node any taints, since you only mentioned about Namespace tolerations?

Comment: Updated the question. Had to re-format it as the code formatting did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Fixed it with:

1. removed whitelist annotation from ns.
2. deployed the pod.
3. `kubectl get pod <pod name> -o yaml`

   in my case, I had a couple of extra toleration injected without me realizing.
4. revert 1 (annotations on ns).